# UWP APP "mrt100_app.dll" Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Suddenly I'm facing "mrt100_app.dll" Cannot find or open the PDB file problem. App Works fine in debug mode. But in release mode build is okay but when starting to deploy the App, its terminated automatically.
When APP start to deploy its shows `Loading mrt100dbi_winamd64.dll` like below image:

[image]

After sometimes App terminated by appearing below message:

[image]

In output console has below log:

[image]

But in `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\` folder  **"mrt100dac_winamd64.dll"** exists.

Also in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\` folder **mrt100_app.dll** exists.

Environment: Visual Studio 17

Comment: Did you check `Microsoft Symbol Servers` under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#symbols) is symbols configuration that you could refer.